# Matching simple keyword and keyword with spaces

Tags: regex, perl, match, keyword, space

I'm currently working on a function which takes a list of keywords and a string(a looong string) as arguments, and i want it to return a list of each matched keyword. Problem is that a keyword can be in 2 words. 
For exemple -  `keyword1 : foobar`, `keyword2 : foo bar`, `keyword3 : barfoo`)

string:

```
hi this is foobar, have you seen my foo bar, he is very fooBar ?
```

i want a list with (`foobar`, `foo bar`);

For the moment i got:

```
@matches = $string =~ m/\b(?:foobar|foo bar)\b/gi ;
```

This works fine for simple words, but not for composed words :/

any idea ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by composed words?

Comment: with a space, like "foo bar", i want it to be one single keyword. I mean I have to do it the fastest way possible , which means scrolling the string only one time.

Comment: Can you give me an example of something you don't want to match?

Comment: Yep , you can have more than one occurence.

Comment: hum "foobar matches but foobardoesnt , whearas foo bar matches , so does FoO BaR" :D

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code. It would match `foobar` but not `foobardoesnt` and both `foo bar` and `FoO BaR`. What do you want to change?

Comment: oh i tried and it didnt work for me , well i'll run a few more tests then

Comment: well it works finally , thx :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sub myfunc {
  my ($str, @kw) = @_;

  my ($re) = map qr/\b ($_) \b/x, join "|", @kw;

  return $str =~ /$re/gi;
}

my @kwords = ("foobar", "foo bar", "barfoo");
my @arr = myfunc("hi this is foobar, have you seen my foo bar, he is very fooBar ?", @kwords);
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns the correct results:

```
sub match {
    my @keywords=@_;
    my $s=pop @keywords;
    return grep {$s=~/\b\Q$_\E\b/i} @keywords;
}

my @matches=match('foobar','foo bar','barfoo)','hi this is foobar, have you seen my foo bar, he is very fooBar?'); #this returns (foobar, foo bar)
```

BTW your code `@matches = $string =~ m/\b(?:foobar|foo bar)\b/gi;` is working great too, if you remove the `/i` modifier it returns (foobar, foo bar)

Comment: well i need the /i because i dont want to to be case sensitive

Comment: ok then, check my response I've updated it to be case insensitive

Comment: You could pass the string in first then use `my ($s, @keywords) = @_;`

Comment: @RobEarl yes you are right, that would better, but I assumed the reverse order since the OP talks about a "function which takes a list of keywords and a string"